# How exactly is the stated composite state of the two registers being produced using the $R_{zz}$ controlled rotations?

Tags: quantum-algorithms, quantum-gate, quantum-state, circuit-construction, hhl-algorithm

<sup>This is a sequel to  [How are two different registers being used as "control"?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/2490/how-are-two-different-registers-being-used-as-control)</sup>

I found the following quantum circuit given in Fig 5 (page 6) of the same paper i.e. [Quantum Circuit Design for Solving Linear Systems of Equations (Cao *et al.*,2012)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1110.2232v2).

[image]

In the above circuit $R_{zz}(\theta)$ is $\left(\begin{matrix}e^{i\theta} & 0 \\ 0 & e^{i\theta}\end{matrix}\right)$

As [@DaftWullie mentions here](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/2490/how-are-two-different-registers-being-used-as-control#comment3055_2494):

> Frankly, I've no chance of getting there because there's an earlier
>   step that I don't understand: **the output on registers $L, M$ after Figure
>   5. The circuit diagram and the claimed output don't match up (the claimed output being separable between the $L$ and $M$ registers, when
>   qubit $l−1$ of register $L$ should be entangled with those of register M.**

I understand that after the Walsh-Hadamard transforms the state of register $L$  is $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2^l}}\sum_{s=0}^{2^l-1}|s\rangle$$

and that of register $M$ is

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2^m}}\sum_{p=0}^{2^m-1}|p\rangle$$

But after that, I'm not exactly sure how they're applying the $R_{zz}$ rotation gates to get to $$\sum_s\sum_p|p\rangle \exp(i p/2^m t_0)|s\rangle$$

Firstly, are all the $R_{zz}$ gates acting on a single qubit i.e. the $l-1$th qubit in the register $L$? (Seems so from the diagram, but I'm not sure).

Secondly, it would be very helpful if some can write down the steps for how're they're getting to $\sum_s\sum_p|p\rangle \exp(i p/2^m t_0)|s\rangle$ using the controlled rotation gates.

Comment: Your statement of $R_{zz}$ can’t be right! I think there are problems with the paper. Unless you get lucky and find someone on here who’s specifically interested in that paper (which is not me!) you’re probably better off directly contacting the authors.

Comment: @DaftWullie By the way, could you just tell me *why* you thought that the $l-1$ th qubit *should* be entangled with Reg M?

Comment: because there are lots of controlled gates acting from a superposition of states on register M onto qubit l-1. That generically is going to create entanglement, whereas the stated output can be created just by acting phase gates on the qubits of M and Not using register L at all. It probably is that phase which is created, but *only* if qubit $l-1$ is in the $|1\rangle$ state.

Comment: @DaftWullie "whereas the stated output can be created just by acting phase gates on the qubits of M and Not using register L at all": How do you introduce the $p$ in $e^{ip/2^mt_0}$ without L?

Comment: @Nelimee That only depends on the index $p$, which is on the register $M$. It has nothing to do with $L$.

Comment: is there are a reason why you are not linking to the latest version of the paper? Also, should this also be tagged with hhl-algorithm?

Comment: @glS A lot of things have been changed in v3 of the paper. v2 deals with a $4\times 4$ system, whereas v3 deals with a $2\times 2$ system. As for the HHL tag, I forgot. Adding it now

Comment: that's weird... if the authors themselves removed some details, I wouldn't trust those details to be correct

Comment: @glS Nelimee [spotted the mistakes](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/74398?m=45450575#45450575) in the paper and simulated the algorithm on QISKit after making some modifications. His code is indeed giving the correct outputs for the system of 4 simultaneous linear equations, which is given in the paper. From what he told me, the part I quoted in the question doesn't have any error.

Comment: Those controlled $R_{zz}(\theta)$ operations don't make any sense. They're strictly more complicated than necessary, because they're equivalent to just applying an $R_z(\theta)$ gate to the control without involving the target.